# Error accountName missing or invalid when trying to get the properties of user using the REST API in my workflow (sharepoint add-in)

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I want to get the user properties of a specific user using this rest api:

```
https://siteurl /_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0#.f|membership|user@test.eu'
```

I keep getting the message:

> The query string *\"accountName\"* is missing or invalid."

When trying this rest api call.

Any ideas?

Thanks!